# Hybris: show error message on storefront

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, storefront

In case a product is offline, I want to show error message on storefront for the same when the user checkouts at cart page. I updated the source code in Controller class and added the error message to GlobalMessages as below:

```
GlobalMessages.addMessage(model, GlobalMessages.ERROR_MESSAGES_HOLDER, "basket.validation.offlineProduct", new Object[] { productData.getName(), productUrl, quantity });
```

I added this error property "basket.validation.offlineProduct" in property file as below:

```
basket.validation.offlineProduct=Unfortunately <a href="{1}">{0}</a> was removed from your cart as it is offline. You previously had {2} in your cart.
```

But the error message is not getting displayed, although on debugging my custom code is being called and error message code is being set to Model.

Other setting required to display error message are already present in jsp file as below:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="common" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/desktop/common" %>
<common:globalMessages/>
```

I checked other Controller file source code, and the process seems to be the same and error message is getting displayed on other pages. I also tried deleting cache and restarting server.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using only text in the properties file. Do not store the html there.

Comment: @Hristo.. I tried using a non-html property as well. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If I was you I'd try to do next things:

1)Try to show message without any parameters, for Example - `"Product was removed from your cart as it is offline"`. If it is working - the problem is in the attributes.

2)Try use something else rather than `GlobalMessages`, like

```
String error = l10NService.getLocalizedString("basket.validation.offlineProduct",new Object[] { productData.getName(), productUrl, quantity });
model.addAttribute("productError", error);
```

Comment: I actually tried both these solutions already. But still it doesn't show the error message on screen. Although, the default hybris error message appear on screen. I think both the solutions should work, but they aren't. May be something is wrong in my code which I'm not able to understand. Thanks!

Comment: I've got it. Well, I think if debug shows that attribute is set to model, but on the storefront Hybris shows some other message - I think you should check if the model is the same for your controller and storefront(add some param and output it, for example).

Comment: Or maybe your message is overwritten somehow

Comment: On storefront, it doesn't show any message for my changes. Yes I checked the model is correct. I checked when the stock is zero (forceOutOfStock), then a default hybris check is done and error message is saved in Model, and the same gets displayed on storefront.